# How can I synchronize getter while a setter is working in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am having a multi-thread application using a single static class which provides a list. I want getters of the static class to work freely (not synchronized against each other) but when a setter is working I want all getters to get locked and wait until setter's job is done. I don't want to lock getters when they are called together since it would degrade performance a lot. Getters are called 1,000,000 times per day and setter is only supposed to work once per day.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider using a `java.util.concurrent.locks.ReadWriteLock` implementation, such as `ReentrantReadWriteLock` (see [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html))

> A `ReadWriteLock` maintains a pair of associated locks, one for read-only operations and one for writing. The read lock may be held simultaneously by multiple reader threads, so long as there are no writers. The write lock is exclusive.

You would use this instead of `synchronized`. Your getters would obtain the read lock, then release when they return, e.g.

```
public String getX() {
    Lock readLock = readWriteLock.readLock();
    readLock.lock();
    try {
        return value;
    } finally {
        readLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Similarly for setters methods, but using `readWriteLock.writeLock()` instead.

The class would have a single `ReentrantReadWriteLock` object, shared by all getters and setters on each object (or, if you wish, one per getter/setter pair).

It's quite cumbersome, but should give good concurrency. For those reasons, you should only take this on if you really need it, and that means measuring the degraded concurrency you get if you just use vanilla synchronization.

Answer (score 6):

Your setter can take a copy of the data on each update and getters can use the copy. This can be very expensive for the setter, but minimal impact for the getters.

However a synchronized lock can be in the order of 25 to 100 ns.  Even if you calling a synchronized method one million times per minute, `synchronized` may not add enough delay to worry about. At one million per second, it definitely will.

Comment: ok then if the delay is in order of ns I wouldnt mind just synchronizing all the methods. Thanks for the information.

Comment: Your second paragraph doesn't seem relevant. The OP doesn't seem to be worried about the overhead of `synchronized` itself; rather, he just doesn't want calls to the getter to have to be sequential. (I think you're right that he shouldn't worry; but the reason not worry is that the getter should be very quick and cheap, not because `synchronized` is.)

Comment: The cost of `synchronized` is usually much higher a method call to a getter.  If you getter is much more expensive that this, its not a regular getter.

Comment: You are describing a CopyOnWriteArrayList, which copies data on each update.  Use it.

Answer (score 3):

I would first synchronize all the accesses, and only optimize if that proves to be a performance problem.

To optimize, you could use a CopyOnWriteArrayList, or a ReadWriteLock. It's hard to give a definitive solution without knowing the context more precisely.

Answer (score 1):

This is the archetypal case to use a CopyOnWriteArrayList.

"This is ordinarily too costly, but may be more efficient than alternatives when traversal operations vastly outnumber mutations, and is useful when you cannot or don't want to synchronize traversals, yet need to preclude interference among concurrent threads. "