# Should getter and setter on String field of a thread have to be synchronized/

Tags: java, multithreading, atomic

I am making a Runnable which will do some independent work but it's progress will be followed by other thread.

In order to do that I put a private String field which contain "the state" of my thread. The thread will update his process by using the setter of this field and other thread will retrieve the state by using the getter.
For the moment, I wrote the following code and I use a lock in order to synchronize my getter and setter.
But I wonder if it is necessary.

I guess my question could be sum up in :
"Does affectation are atomic in Java"

Thank you in advance, if you took the time to read my question.

```java
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class FollowedThread implements Runnable {
    private String state;
    private final Lock lock;

    public FollowedThread() {
        lock = new ReentrantLock();
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            this.state = state;
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public String getState() {
        String result;
        lock.lock();
        try {
            result = state;
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        setState("Step 1 running");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            setState("Step 2 running");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            setState("Step 3 running");
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            setState("Thread finished");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            setState("Thread interrupted");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Off topic, but why use `Lock` when you can simply do `synchronized(state)` ?

Comment: It looks like you may find this post useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195506/how-can-i-synchronize-getter-while-a-setter-is-working-in-java

Comment: @Nizil, thank you you right, I did this because I am not familiar with concurrency in Java. It's a reflex of my C system homework when I was a student.

Comment: Just declare it `volatile`, no other synchronization is needed. Object references are assigned atomically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found my answer.
In order to ensure atomic access to a field, you have to declare it [volatile](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile.shtml).
With it my code become :

```java
package com.afklm.myactu.util;

public class FollowedThread implements Runnable {
    private volatile String state;

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        setState("Step 1 running");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            setState("Step 2 running");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            setState("Step 3 running");
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            setState("Thread finished");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            setState("Thread interrupted");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That will do it. Hence you can get rid off the lock completely now.

Comment: Actually, You have to use *volatile* to ensure a *happens-before* relation. This forces flushing of processer / local thread cache and re-reading of updated value from main memory. SO all the threads will be able to read updated value. Since you are just *re-assigning* the reference, *volatile* will be sufficient. Use synchronization when there are multiple instructions inside a method/code block.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary. Nothing is going to be corrupted since this is an atomic operation. Worst case scenario your getter will get an old value. The lock is not necessary for an atomic operation.

Now the big question is how important is it that the getter gets the absolute most recent value? If this is tied into other synchronization, then maybe. Adding the `volatile` keyword to `state` is probably a good idea to avoid the data getting too stale.

Comment: Believing to this article http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile.shtml. If you don't declare your field has volatif, it is not sure that affectation is atomic.

Comment: do you have a reliable source affirming affectation of object are atomic ?